# Develop WP 8 apps in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have downloaded the WP 8 SDK. It actually installed some Visual Studio Express 2012. I dont want that. How do I open and run my WP 8 projects in Visual Studio 2013? Please Help!

Comment: Are you using win7 or win8 OS ?

Comment: Visual Studio 3013 Update 3